# Long-running loops in JavaScript and UI responsiveness

Tags: javascript, loops, firefox, recursion, browser

I had a code that processes a huge JSON array in a "for" loop.

```
for(var i = 0; item = arr[i]; i++) {
   //PROCESS item
}
```

The issue was with a Firefox browser. It shows a warning dialog that script is running too long. The following code was the solution

```
//not precise code example, but it's kind of.
delay(arr, 0);

function delay(arr, num) {
   //process array by parts with 50 elements in each part
   for(var i = 1; i <= 50; i++) { 
      //PROCESS arr[num];
      num += i;
   }
   if(num < arr.length) {
      setTimeout(function() { delay(arr, num); }, 100);
   }
}
```

I wondering if there is a more fabulous way to workaround complete UI freeze and make Firefox to don't show script debug dialog. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Firefox, you might be looking for [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers), which allows you to spawn background threads.

Comment: I was hoping that there is some cross-browser solution, because other browsers are getting frozen as well, just without dialog boxes. And the CPU load on user's PC is 100% of course.

Comment: As best I can tell Web Workers are supported in Chrome, IE10+, Safari, etc. See here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers

Answer (score 1):

I think web workers are what you need.

Here you can find an good introduction to web workers: [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/)